# Combined fit of two distributions

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, data-fitting, iminuit

I have two separate distributions given by the functions `P_multiple` and `P_single`. I would like to combine the two and into one combined fit function which has a natural "transition" between the two. Do you have suggestions? Thank you!

Here is the plot I have versus what I'd like to get (in red).[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def P_multiple(alpha):
    return 1 / np.sqrt(np.pi) * np.exp(-alpha**2)

def P_single(alpha, Z):
    alpha_abs = np.abs(alpha)
    return 1 / (alpha_abs**3 * 8 * np.log(204 * Z**(-1/3)))

Z_silicon = 14 
alpha_threshold = 3 
alpha_values = np.linspace(-7, 7, 300)

multiple = P_multiple(alpha_values)
single = P_single(alpha_values, Z_silicon)

multiple[np.abs(alpha_values) > alpha_threshold] = 0
single[np.abs(alpha_values) <= alpha_threshold] = 0

combined_distribution = multiple + single

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(alpha_values, multiple, label='Multiple')
plt.plot(alpha_values, single, label='Single')
plt.plot(alpha_values, combined_distribution, label='Combined', linestyle='--')

plt.legend()
plt.yscale('log') 
plt.show()
```

Later edit:

I have done a bit of digging for some simplified formula that might help in this respect. I found an answer in [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.2759.pdf).
Following this, I've tried to generate some data and then fit it using scipy's `curve_fit` and `minuit` minimization. `curve_fit` seems to work to some extent, but the fit is not perfect. Minuit works to some extent, but the initial fit is translated on the y axis. I managed to use a scaling factor to make the fit visually ok, but the chi2 per degree of freedom is very bad. The scaling might not be what I need.
Any suggestions? The code I paste below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import gamma
from iminuit import Minuit

def P_multiple(alpha):
    return 1 / np.sqrt(np.pi) * np.exp(-alpha**2)

def P_single(alpha, Z):
    alpha_abs = np.abs(alpha)
    return 1 / (alpha_abs**3 * 8 * np.log(204 * Z**(-1/3)))

# The fit function (sum of a Gaussian and a Student's t-distribution)
def fit_function(theta, N, a, mu, sigma_g, sigma, tail_parameter):
    gaussian_part = (1 - a) * np.exp(-((theta - mu) ** 2) / (2 * sigma_g ** 2)) / (sigma_g * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))
    t_part = (a * gamma((tail_parameter + 1) / 2) / (np.sqrt(tail_parameter * np.pi) * sigma * gamma(tail_parameter / 2)) *
             np.power(1 + ((theta - mu) ** 2) / (tail_parameter * sigma ** 2), -(tail_parameter + 1) / 2))
    return N * (gaussian_part + t_part)

def binned_likelihood(params, theta, counts, bin_width):
    N, a, mu, sigma_g, sigma, tail_parameter = params
    expected_counts = fit_function(theta, N, a, mu, sigma_g, sigma, tail_parameter) * bin_width
    # Using Poisson likelihood
    return -2 * np.sum(counts * np.log(expected_counts) - expected_counts)

# Cost function for Minuit
def cost_function(N, a, mu, sigma_g, sigma, tail_parameter):
    params = [N, a, mu, sigma_g, sigma, tail_parameter]
    expected_counts = fit_function(bin_centers, *params) * bin_width
    expected_counts = np.maximum(expected_counts, 1e-6)  # Ensure non-zero expected counts
    cost = -2 * np.sum(counts * np.log(expected_counts) - expected_counts)
    return cost

Z_silicon = 14 
alpha_threshold = 3 
alpha_values = np.linspace(-7, 7, 300)

multiple = P_multiple(alpha_values)
single = P_single(alpha_values, Z_silicon)

multiple[np.abs(alpha_values) > alpha_threshold] = 0
single[np.abs(alpha_values) <= alpha_threshold-1.5] = 0

combined_distribution = multiple + single

# Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) -- thanks chatGPT
cdf = cumtrapz(combined_distribution, alpha_values, initial=0)
cdf /= cdf[-1]  # normalized CDF
inverse_cdf = interp1d(cdf, alpha_values) # Interpolation function for the inverse CDF

# Data
num_samples = 100000
uniform_samples = np.random.uniform(0, 1, num_samples)
generated_samples = inverse_cdf(uniform_samples)

num_bins = 300
counts, bins = np.histogram(generated_samples, bins=num_bins)
bin_centers = 0.5 * (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])
errors = np.sqrt(counts)  # Poisson error per bin
bin_width = bins[1] - bins[0]


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.errorbar(bin_centers, counts, yerr=errors, fmt='o', label='Data with Error Bars', color='#1E88E5', ecolor='black', zorder=1)
plt.plot(alpha_values, combined_distribution * num_samples / np.sum(combined_distribution), label='Distribution from which data is drawn', linestyle='--', color ='red', zorder=2)

params = [4500, 0.02, 0, 0.7, 3, 5] # played quite a bit to get those
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_function, bin_centers, counts, p0=params, sigma=errors)

theta_values = np.linspace(min(generated_samples), max(generated_samples), 500)
fitted_function_values = fit_function(theta_values, *popt)
plt.plot(theta_values, fitted_function_values, label='Fitted function (curve_fit)', color='#004D40', zorder=3)

### minuit below
# total_samples = np.sum(counts)
# bin_width = bins[1] - bins[0]
# scale_factor = total_samples * bin_width
# print(scale_factor)
m = Minuit(cost_function, N=10000, a=0.3, mu=0, sigma_g=0.7, sigma=3, tail_parameter=3)
m.limits['sigma_g', 'sigma', 'tail_parameter'] = (1e-6, None) # parameter limits
m.errordef = Minuit.LEAST_SQUARES
m.migrad()
m.hesse()

fitted_params_minuit = [m.values[key] for key in m.parameters]
fitted_function_scaled = fit_function(theta_values, *fitted_params_minuit)*0.05
plt.plot(theta_values, fitted_function_scaled, label='Fitted Function (Minuit)', color='green')


plt.xlabel('Angle')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.legend()
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim(0.5,1e4)
plt.show()

# Chi2 for curve_fit
adjusted_errors = np.where(errors == 0, 1, errors)
chi2_curve_fit = np.sum(((counts - fit_function(bin_centers, *popt)) / adjusted_errors) ** 2)
dof_curve_fit = len(counts) - len(popt)
chi2_per_dof_curve_fit = chi2_curve_fit / dof_curve_fit
print("curve_fit - Fitted parameters:", popt)
print("curve_fit - Chi-squared:", chi2_curve_fit)
print("curve_fit - Chi-squared per degree of freedom:", chi2_per_dof_curve_fit)

# Chi-squared for Minuit
chi2_minuit = np.sum(((counts - fit_function(bin_centers, *fitted_params_minuit)) / adjusted_errors) ** 2)
dof_minuit = len(counts) - len(fitted_params_minuit)
chi2_per_dof_minuit = chi2_minuit / dof_minuit
print("Minuit - Fitted parameters:", fitted_params_minuit)
print("Minuit - Chi-squared:", chi2_minuit)
print("Minuit - Chi-squared per degree of freedom:", chi2_per_dof_minuit)
```

Results:

```
curve_fit - Fitted parameters: [4.5e+03 2.0e-02 0.0e+00 7.0e-01 3.0e+00 5.0e+00]
curve_fit - Chi-squared: 1087.3770894509803
curve_fit - Chi-squared per degree of freedom: 3.698561528744831
Minuit - Fitted parameters: [100032.27417296321, 0.0780285341472854, -0.001452392031778836, 0.7125402555391692, 0.7478831473831798, 2.673494961387995]
Minuit - Chi-squared: 42899843.300199464
Minuit - Chi-squared per degree of freedom: 145917.83435441996
```

Resulting fit:

[image]

I followed the advice in the comments to look for a function, but I admit I don't really know what I'm doing here apart from trial and error :)

Comment: What makes the red line a good fit based on the data? It ignores the gaps.

Comment: The gaps are parametrizations of the behavior at the different regions. The overall red distribution I am trying to get is physics motivated (i.e. Moliere theory -- comprised of a inner Gaussian core and long tails given by Rutherford scattering). I did not want to simply combine two Gaussians, one wide, the other narrow.

Comment: Is there a function that defines the red curve which you need to find the parameters for?

Comment: There is, but it's extremely complicated to model (involves too many unknowns also). This is why we use these parametrizations for different regimes.

Comment: So is there a simplified function that defines the red curve which you need to find parameters for? I mean, there are zillions of way to find a "smooth" function that fits as much as possible the 2 distributions. But since that is contradictory (in reality, a distribution cannot be both smooth and fit the 2 distributions), it need to define how we approach it, where to we put the cursor between smoothness and fitting, etc. But all methods (interpolation, projection on a vector-space of some basic functions, regression, even ML) would be defining a family of functions that red curve belongs to

Comment: On example of such method, could be to consider the red curve to be the weighted sum of two gaussians, one wide the other narrow. But you explicitly said you don't want that. Which means that your have a preconception of what family of functions we are looking for, since you know "sum of 2 gaussians" is not in. Could you maybe share your preconceptions? Because else, we are doomed to enumerate the zillions possibilities, and wait for you to tell us that you don't like them.

Comment: @chrslg I followed your advice and tried to look for a simplified function. I have implemented it, and got some data point from it. Now, I would like to use Minuit to fit the function and get a satisfactory chi2 per degree of freedom. I had to tweak (using a scaling factor) the function to visually look ok (otherwise it was translated on the y axis on top of my data points). As a result, the chi2 per dof explodes :) I probably still did not fit good and would appreciate any advice!

Comment: PS: I know that scaling the chi2 by doing `chi2_minuit = np.sum(((counts - fit_function(bin_centers, *fitted_params_minuit)*0.05) / adjusted_errors) ** 2)`
gives right ballpark values, but I am not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of ways of doing this, but I thought I'd find a method that looked similar to what you showed in what you wanted, while I only implemented for one side, I've been on this for a bit too long now and it shouldn't be too hard to make it work
I decided to implement this using [bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), which have the con of using a t variable which means it is harder to find exact values for a certain x or a certain y unless you have a high sample rate, as I didn't really know what you are implementing this for, I just went with this as this was my first thought to make it look the closest
Bezier curves are essentially just a way of making a curve using three points

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def P_multiple(alpha):
    return 1 / np.sqrt(np.pi) * np.exp(-alpha**2)

def P_single(alpha, Z):
    alpha_abs = np.abs(alpha)
    return 1 / (alpha_abs**3 * 8 * np.log(204 * Z**(-1/3)))

def findcrosspoint(error, dotpoints, valuem, values):
    #finds the closest point of crossing by approximation
    for i in range (dotpoints-1, 0, -1):
        if abs(values[i] - valuem[i]) <= error:
            return i
    return -1

def bezierline(startpoint, endpoint, t):
    # creates a bezier line
    return startpoint + t * (endpoint-startpoint)

def beziercurve(startpoint, crosspoint, endpoint, res):
    curvevals = []
    for i in range(res):
        if i != 0:
            t = i / res
        else:
            t = i
            
        # curves between two bezier lines
        curvevals.append(bezierline(startpoint, crosspoint, t) + t * (bezierline(crosspoint, endpoint, t) - bezierline(startpoint, crosspoint, t)))
    return np.array(curvevals)

def transition(Z, dotpoints, viewsize, startpoint, thresh, transitionrange, xweight, yweight):
    # calculates all the values
    xs = np.linspace(startpoint, startpoint+viewsize, dotpoints)
    valuem = P_multiple(xs)
    values = P_single(xs, Z)
    transitionpoint = thresh

    # calculates start, cross and endpoints to calculate the bezier curve
    startpoint = transitionpoint - transitionrange
    startpoint = np.array([startpoint, np.log(P_multiple(startpoint))])
    crosspoint = findcrosspoint(0.1, dotpoints, np.log(valuem), np.log(values)) * (viewsize/dotpoints)
    
    # the x and y weight allow you to change the position of the cross point which can change the look of the curve
    crosspoint = np.array([crosspoint / xweight, np.log(P_multiple(crosspoint) / yweight)])
    plt.scatter(np.array([crosspoint[0]]), np.array([crosspoint[1]]), s=20, label='cross')
    plt.scatter(np.array([startpoint[0]]), np.array([startpoint[1]]), s=20, label='start')
    endpoint = transitionpoint + transitionrange
    endpoint = np.array([endpoint, np.log(P_single(endpoint, Z))])
    plt.scatter(np.array([endpoint[0]]), np.array([endpoint[1]]), s=20, label='end')

    # calculates the bezier curve values
    curvevals = beziercurve(startpoint, crosspoint, endpoint, 10000)
    # puts them all back into one array
    values = []
    inserted = False
    for i in range(xs.shape[0]):
        if xs[i] <= startpoint[0]:
            values.append([xs[i], np.log(P_multiple(xs[i]))])
        elif xs[i] >= endpoint[0]:
            values.append([xs[i], np.log(P_single(xs[i], Z))])
        elif inserted == False:
            for value in curvevals:
                values.append(np.array([value[0], value[1]]))
            inserted = True
    return np.array(values)


Z_silicon = 14
alpha_threshold = 3
alpha_values = np.linspace(-7, 7, 500)

multiple = P_multiple(alpha_values)
single = P_single(alpha_values, Z_silicon)

multiple[np.abs(alpha_values) > alpha_threshold] = 0
single[np.abs(alpha_values) <= alpha_threshold] = 0

combined_distribution = multiple + single

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(alpha_values, np.log(multiple), label='Multiple')
plt.plot(alpha_values, np.log(single), label='Single')
values = transition(Z_silicon, 1000, 7, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1)
xs = np.zeros(values.shape[0])
ys = np.zeros(values.shape[0])
for i in range(values.shape[0]):
    xs[i] = values[i][0]
    ys[i] = values[i][1]
plt.plot(xs, ys, label='combined')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

While this code is crude, it does closely match what you drew in your graph. It is fairly adjustable so you can make it look more to your liking

[1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fynj.png)

[2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgvkA.png)

EDIT:
forgot to mention this looked fairly weird when i used it with a log scale so i logged the values instead, I'm sorry if this is an inconvenience

Comment: This looks very nice! And this gave me the idea of using it to find an intersection point between the two curves I had and do a weighted mean average. However, the results were not satisfactory :( And indeed, I also need the log function to emphasize the contribution of the tails for an argument I am making.